# Shopping Spree - Simple Logic Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

> **The Hello World of Grid Based Logic Puzzles**

*Shopping Spree*

Bill and Mary went shopping. They brought home a TV, and a new Tablet, one cost 100, the other 200. One transaction was paid in cash, the other in credit.

Figure out who bought what, how they paid, and the amount of the item:

**Clues:**

1. Bill did not pay cash and Tv cost more than tablet.
2. The 200 item was paid by credit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> According to 1, the TV costs 200, the tablet costs 100, Bill paid in credit and Mary by cash. Combined with 2, it means Bill paid 200 for the TV in credit while Mary paid 100 for the tablet in cash.

Answer (score 2):

I think:

> Bill paid 200 by credit for the TV. Mary paid 100 cash for the tablet.

Based on:

> Bill paid credit (1a), 200 (2) and for the TV (1b).